# fabric.js construct groups on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm trying to create several groups. Each of the group will get a custom attribute to indicate its position. Depending on this attribute I want to set different images as a group members. This part doesn't work and I cannot figure it out. image header.png is added twice and shows in content-footer area. in the header area there is no image at all.

Also when I try to log the output

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(canvasBuild)
```

there is no content inside the "objects" property of a group. When I try to log stringified group - it does show the image objects.

This is the simplified code so far

```
var hasHeader = false;
var hasFooter = false;

//  users choice of layout      
var customPosition = [];

$(this).siblings('.layoutOptions').children('input:checked').each(function(i) 
{
   customPosition[i] =  $(this).val();                  
   if ( customPosition[i]=='content-header'){
        hasHeader = true;
   }else if (customPosition[i]=='content-footer'){
     hasFooter = true;
   }
 });

 $(this).siblings('.contentOptions').children('input:checked').val();
    for (i = 0; i< customPosition.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
        console.log(customPosition[i]);

        var canvField = (canvasBHeight - shadowBVal*2) - strokeBWidth*2;

        if (customPosition[i] == 'content-header'){
            //header positioning

            var group = new fabric.Group([],{
                left: strokeBWidth + 10,
                stroke: '#ddd',
                strokeLineJoin: 'round',
                strokeWidth: 2,
                hasControls:  true, 
                lockMovementX: false, 
                lockMovementY: false, 
                lockRotation: true,
                selectable: true,
                position: posB,
                fill: '#ccc',
                width: ((canvasBWidth - shadowBVal*2) - strokeBWidth*2 - 10),
                //height: canvasBHeight/5 - strokeBWidth,
                height: canvField/5,
                top: strokeBWidth,
                ry: 0,
                rx: 20,
                //originX: 'center',
                //originY: 'center'
            });

            //add dummy content

            fabric.Image.fromURL('image/bordenconfigurator/dummies/header.png', function(oImg) {
                                        oImg.set({

                                            });

                                            group.add(oImg);
                                            console.log('group '+i+' '+customPosition[i]+':');
                                            console.log(JSON.stringify(group));
                                            //console.log(group);

                                });

        }else if(customPosition[i] == 'content-footer') {
            console.log(customPosition[i]);
            //footer positioning
            var group = new fabric.Group([],{
                left: strokeBWidth + 10,
                stroke: '#ddd',
                strokeLineJoin: 'round',
                strokeWidth: 2,
                hasControls:  true, 
                lockMovementX: false, 
                lockMovementY: false, 
                lockRotation: true,
                selectable: true,
                position: posB,
                fill: '#ccc',
                width: ((canvasBWidth - shadowBVal*2) - strokeBWidth*2 - 10),
                //height: canvasBHeight/5 - strokeBWidth,
                height: canvField/5,
                top: strokeBWidth + canvField*4/5 + 10,
                ry: 0,
                rx: 20,
                //originX: 'center',
                //originY: 'center'
            });

            //add dummy content

            fabric.Image.fromURL('image/bordenconfigurator/dummies/footer.png', function(oImg) {
                                        oImg.set({
                                            top: canvasBHeight- strokeBWidth-shadowBVal,
                                            });

                                            group.add(oImg);
                                            canvasBuild.centerObjectH(oImg);
                                        console.log('group '+i+' '+customPosition[i]+':');
                                                console.log(JSON.stringify(group));
                                });

        }else{
            console.log(customPosition[i]);
            //body positioning
            var height,top;

            if (hasHeader === true && hasFooter === true){
                height = canvField*3/5 + 5;
                top = strokeBWidth + canvField/5 + 5;
            }else if(hasHeader ===true && hasFooter === false){
                height = canvField*4/5 + 5;
                top = strokeBWidth + canvField/5 + 5;
            }else if(hasHeader ===false && hasFooter === true){
                height = canvField*4/5;
                top = strokeBWidth + 5;
            }

                var group = new fabric.Group([],{
                    left: strokeBWidth + 10,
                    stroke: '#ddd',
                    strokeLineJoin: 'round',
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    hasControls:  true, 
                    lockMovementX: false, 
                    lockMovementY: false, 
                    lockRotation: true,
                    selectable: true,
                    position: posB,
                    fill: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                    width: ((canvasBWidth - shadowBVal*2) - strokeBWidth*2 - 10),

                    height: height,
                    //top: strokeBWidth + canvField/5 + 5,
                    top: top,
                    ry: 20,
                    rx: 20
            });
        }


        group.toObject = (function(toObject) {
            return function() {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                    customPosition: this.customPosition,
                    label: this.label,
                    id: this.id
                });
            };

        })(group.toObject);

        group.customPosition = customPosition[i];
        group.id = posB;

        canvasBuild.add(group);

        group.length = 0;
        posB++;
    }

    //addOrientationLines();
    //canvasBuild.renderAll();
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(canvasBuild));
});
```